# AnyDice: How can I compare highest roll of two dices with another result?

Tags: anydice

My question is that I want a system where I am always rolling 2 dices *(let's say 1d4 & 1d8)* to get the highest result of these two. Then, roll the difficulty with another dice *(let's say 1d6)* and compare these results to see what are the odds of a **failure**, a **tie**, and a **success** for different difficult dices.

I don't know how to make it on AnyDice to have precise numbers. Can someone help me?

Comment: Hello there! Welcome to RPG.SE! Have a look at [tour] and to [help] to some guidance about posting Questions and Answers here. Is the second die (in your example the d6) setting the number that you should overcome with the highest of the other twos to check if you succeed or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Part 1: `highest of A and B` for skill dice

```
output [highest of 1d4 and 1d8]
```

[You can even chain that, which you can see in action here](https://anydice.com/program/2deb2)

### Part 2: `>1d6` for comparison to difficulty dice

```
output [highest of 1d4 and 1d8]>1d6
```

This compares the highest of the two dice with the 1d6, and if it's higher, it's a 1, otherwise a 0.

[The end result using > = < is this](https://anydice.com/program/2deb6):

61.46 % higher, 12.50 % Tie, 26.04 % smaller for a difficulty die of 1d6.

### Adaption is simple!

To adapt, just alter the dice in the upper portion of [**this Script**](https://anydice.com/program/2deb7):

```
SKILL_A: 1d4
SKILL_B: 1d8
DIFF: 1d6

output [highest of SKILL_A and SKILL_B]>DIFF named "Higher"
output [highest of SKILL_A and SKILL_B]=DIFF named "Equal"
output [highest of SKILL_A and SKILL_B]<DIFF named "Lower"
```

### Streamling with functions

Anydice allows running functions. And [Ilmari Karonen](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/204858/anydice-how-can-i-compare-highest-roll-of-two-dices-with-another-result#comment561348_204859) did a very quick streamline on it, that allows working from it later.

Larger, equal, and smaller than can be seen as "[this] - [that]" and then seeing a positive, 0 or negative value. So just to see 1, 0 and -1, you can truncate it with:

```
function: sign of N:n {
  if N < 0 { result: -1 }
  if N > 0 { result: 1 }
  result: 0
}
```

The operative line then becomes

```
output [sign of [highest of SKILL_A and SKILL_B] - DIFF] named "1 = higher, 0 = equal, -1 = lower"
```

Resulting in [this script](https://anydice.com/program/2debc)