# AnyDice: Savage World but with an Exploding dice instead of 4

Tags: savage-worlds, anydice

So I'm exploring some mechanics and I want to use Exploding Rolls, similar to Savage World, but I'm curious about the statistics of also having an **exploding difficulty**.

For example:

I roll 1d6 and 1d8, both can explode but I keep the highest result
*vs*
1d4 for difficulty (this dice would raise to fit more difficult situations, like 1d6, 1d8 etc).

I'm having trouble to come up with a system so I can compare different skill dices and difficulty dices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### So far...

[You know the code for the function without exploding dice.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/204858/anydice-how-can-i-compare-highest-roll-of-two-dices-with-another-result)

### Part 3 `explode`

You need to tell your code that the dice do explode, which is part of the `explode` function. with proper brackets in the comparison, so for example `[highest of [explode 1d4] and [explode 1d8]]` to have skill dice explode or `[explode 1d6]` to have a single d6 explode.

### Adapted code

```
SKILL_A: 1d4
SKILL_B: 1d8
DIFF: 1d6

function: sign of N:n {
  if N < 0 { result: -1 }
  if N > 0 { result: 1 }
  result: 0
}

output [sign of [highest of SKILL_A and SKILL_B] - [explode DIFF]] named "1 = higher, 0 = equal, -1 = lower"
```

or with comparison: [here](https://anydice.com/program/2dedd)

Answer (score 8):

You can use the same solution(s) as for [your previous question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/204858/anydice-how-can-i-compare-highest-roll-of-two-dices-with-another-result), but wrap the rolls you want to explode with the `[explode DIE]` function from AnyDice's built-in Function Library, e.g. [like this](https://anydice.com/program/2deda):

```
function: sign of N:n {
  if N < 0 { result: -1 }
  if N > 0 { result: 1 }
  result: 0
}

SKILL_A: d4
SKILL_B: d8
DIFF: d6

output [sign of [highest of SKILL_A and SKILL_B] - DIFF] named "no explode (-1 = failure, 0 = tie, 1 = success)"

SKILL_A: [explode d4]
SKILL_B: [explode d8]

output [sign of [highest of SKILL_A and SKILL_B] - DIFF] named "only skill dice explode (-1 = failure, 0 = tie, 1 = success)"

DIFF: [explode d6]

output [sign of [highest of SKILL_A and SKILL_B] - DIFF] named "all dice explode (-1 = failure, 0 = tie, 1 = success)"
```

The `[explode DIE]` function takes any die and returns an exploding version of that die.  So, for example, `[explode d6]` is an exploding d6.  It does have a few notable quirks that should be kept in mind:

- `[explode 2d6]` is a single 2d6 roll that explodes (i.e. gets another 2d6 roll added to it) on a roll of 12 (the maximum possible result).  If you instead want to roll two d6's that each explode on a roll of 6, you need to write that as `2d[explode d6]`.
- To keep the range of possible results limited, AnyDice  by default only lets dice explode at most twice.  You can adjust this limit with `set "explode depth" to N`, where `N` is some number (the default value being 2) if you want.
- The `[explode DIE]` function always produces dice that explode on the highest possible roll, adding a reroll of the same die to the original roll.  If you'd prefer to use some other explosion rule, you need to write your own custom function.  There's [an AnyDice blog post about exploding dice](https://anydice.com/articles/exploding-dice/) that goes into this in more detail.

Comment: it's more economous  on the code to put the explodes in the output line than re-defining the dice

Comment: @Trish: Sure, but having too many nested functions can also become hard to read at some point. Variables are cheap and help readability. (Also, I was trying to drive home the point that the _only_ thing the OP needs to change is the definition of the dice; the calculation is otherwise exactly the same whether the dice explode or not.)